# Scan and access local file directory in Firefox and IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, activex

I'm doing some research on whether or not it's possible for a web app (meant to be used and distributed internally) to scan and read files from a local directory (on user machine). I came across a couple of terms as following:

- NPAPI: no longer supported by majority of web browser
- ActiveX: IE only
- Sandbox: Chrome uses this kind of technology, plus it's not fitting to the requirement so I have to look elsewhere

I feel like ActiveX might be the only option even though I haven't actually written any ActiveX control before (not sure if it's possible).

Also the goal is to support more than one kind of web browser, so other than IE I thought Firefox might be capable of achieving the requirement, since no search result so far said otherwise.

Could someone please give me some pointer? I just need to know if it's at all possible to build a ActiveX control or Firefox extension to scan and read files from a local directory. If it is, then what is the downside other than security vulnerability.

Comment: Use Windows Remote desktop to gain access to the client PC with the users consent on Domain networks. You can also use it to gain consented access to your friends computers with their consent, but you cannot use it to run a fake support scam site.